# Does SO still need separate tags for Oracle, Oracle10g and Oracle11g?

Tags: discussion, tags

I can't think of too many instances (on StackOverflow) where someone has asked a question, where knowing if they're on 10g or 11g really affects the answer.  The exception being in how LOBs are handled (I'm sure there are others), but I don't recall too many of those being asked lately.  In fact [of the 10 most-relevant LOB questions asked](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle%20lob&submit=search), the OPs all used the generic "Oracle" tag, and only one person used an additional "Oracle11g" tag.

Now I can think of many DBA-related tasks where it *does* matter, but those questions belong on dba.stackexchange.com and not SO.  And if someone should ask a question where 10g vs. 11g does make a difference, they probably have a better chance at getting a good answer if it gets migrated to dba.stackexchange.com anyway.

So in-terms of a question that *a developer would ask*, does it make sense to still keep the 10g/11g tags around on SO?

Comment: hmm what about the `9i` questions? Also what happens if the next version of Oracle comes out and has a lot of SO type changes? Should the user have to guess which version the answer applies to?

Comment: @ConradFrix Most of the (SO-relevant) Oracle-based questions that are asked generally relate to SQL & PL/SQL, which really hasn't changed much.

Comment: Honestly, I'm on the fence about 9i.  I didn't mention it because you could argue that it should be separate just based-on its age.

Comment: Well here's one were version matters [How to retrieve data from different rows of the same table based on different criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9025650/119477)

Comment: @ConradFrix good find, let me admit that I might be wrong.  Maybe it's not so much that the separate tags exist, but rather in how they are used.  Post your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So in-terms of a question that a developer would ask, does it make sense to still keep the 10g/11g tags around on SO?

Yes. There are [several features](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28279/chapter1.htm) introduced in 11g, that cannot be used in Oracle 10g. Having separate tag helps in preventing people answering on these tags give answers that cannot be applied on other versions.

You can argue that the version information can be provided in the question, but when it comes to searching, the tag *really* helps.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the Oracle 10g and 11g tags are still being used.  Now whether or not they are being used *correctly* is a separate issue all together.  As Conrad Frix pointed-out, there still are valid SO questions being asked in which the version of Oracle does matter.  Although I'm thinking that in 99% of them it does not.  Regardless, if nobody else sees an issue with the current state of these tags, then we might as well leave it the way it is.

Comment: +1, I've asked one that was Oracle 11g specific.